# why do we reshape grayscale image to (x,y,1)?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I noticed that when training CNN with a grayscale image. The dimensions of the image is reshaped to (x,y,1). I thought that this shouldn't be necessary but when i try with shape (x,y). I get an error

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 28, 28]
```

As i understand the only reason we are doing this because keras implemented this way. Or is there any other reason for this?

Comment: the 1 is the number of channels, grey scale images have only one channel, RGB images have 3 channels, just go study what a channel is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input shape of of `Conv2D` layer in keras is: `batch_size + (rows, cols, channels)`. So, the layer expects number of channels as the final input shape which is 1 for grayscale image. For RGB images this would be 3.